# Request.CreateResponse missing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

Visual Studio 2019 new project Core, webAPI template project.

Controller file that comes with the project starts as such  (I added .Net namespaces)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web;




    namespace testwebapi.Controllers
    {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
        {

           public HttpResponseMessage Get(string gender = "All")
           {
                  Request.CreateResponse()
           }
       }
  }
```

however the .CreateRequest() does not exist. Request is (AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest ControllerBase.Request) and I think that is wrong but I do not know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

looks like I was using the wrong project type.
it does not appear to exist in the Core version of Api web. I still need to learn the difference and why that is